# how to store a reference to a object or a global object with angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, firebase, ionic-framework

I hope the title of this question makes sense. What i need is a way of storing a reference to a object in a controller and access it in another one.

For example, i have a `AppCtrl` where i initiate firebase:

```
.controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope, $ionicModal, $timeout, $firebase) {
        var ref = new Firebase("https://test.firebaseio.com/");
        var sync = $firebase(ref);
        $scope.db = sync.$asObject();

        var authClient = new FirebaseSimpleLogin(ref, function(error, user) {
            if (error) {
            } else if (user) {
                console.log(user);
            } else {
                // user is logged out
            }
        });

        ...
```

In another controller i want to do `authClient.logout()` but `authClient` is not available:

```
.controller('LogoutCtrl', function ($scope, $stateParams, $firebase) {
        authClient.logout();
})
```

Is there a way to access `authClient` in the second controller without the need to instantiating `FirebaseSimpleLogin`, like grabbing it from a global var?

I'm not sure what is the best approach, maybe is a good idea to instantiate it again..

I'm using `firebase` as an example here, but this could be any other class

any ideas?

Comment: You should be using a service for that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case angular suggests to use [Services](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services)

Angular services are substitutable objects that are wired together using dependency injection (DI). You can use services to organize and share code across your app.

**UPDATE**

---

[example](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire-seed/blob/master/app/js/simpleLogin.js) of using simple login with firebase and angular

Comment: An example of said service, wrapping FirebaseSimpleLogin, can be [found in angularFire-seed](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire-seed/blob/master/app/js/simpleLogin.js)

Comment: I recently created my first AngularJS service for the same need. Less versatile than the one from angularFire-seed, but that one doesn't fit in a comment: `app.constant('FBURL', "https://myfirebase.firebaseio.com/");
app.factory('$firebaseAuth', function($firebase, $firebaseSimpleLogin, FBURL) { return $firebaseSimpleLogin(new Firebase(FBURL)); });`